# Is it possible to have a JS function without using script tags?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML, I am writing a basic button that calls a function

```
<button onclick="text('Hello World')">Hello World</button>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/AYp15C6j"></script>
```

The Pastebin link simply says this

```
function text(t) {
alert(t); 
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to call the external link/function in without using the script tag **(and not just replacing text('Hello World') with alert('Hello World'))**, something theoretically like:

```
<button src="https://pastebin.com/raw/AYp15C6j" onclick="text('Hello World')">Hello World</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot. The external function must be included as a script in the HTML, and the `script` tag exactly does this.

Comment: Avoid XY problem. What are you trying to do? Obfuscate your HTML?

Comment: Agreed. This is a very strange thing to ask for. What are you actually trying to do? See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: [You being new to programming is completely unrelated to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Remove it.

Comment: [Or probably for XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435077/execute-javascript-for-xss-without-script-tags) (<-- possible duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways of adding javascript.

```html
<button onclick="text('Hello World')">Hello World</button>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/AYp15C6j"></script>
```

```html
<button onclick="text('Hello World')">Hello World</button>
<script>
function text(t) {
    alert(t);
}
</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="text('Hello World'); function text(t) {alert(t);}">Hello World</button>
```

[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you need a script tag inside html page for a JS Function.
but in the following case you does not need script for JS function.

Example here:

```
  <button src="https://pastebin.com/raw/AYp15C6j" onclick="alert('Hello World'); 
    ">Hello World</button>
```

onclick="alert('Hello World')"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it helps, but you can write code in onclick handler, like this:

```html
<button onclick="f=function(t){alert(t);};f('Hello World');">Hello World</button>
```

or like this:

```html
<button onclick="window[(!![]+'')[3]+'v'+(![]+'')[1]+(![]+'')[2]](atob('YWxlcnQoJ0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkJyk='));">Hello World</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` in your button tag is an attribute that fires on a mouse click on the element and it defines the code that must be executed in that event.

You can define the code to be executed right after the equal sign:

`<button onclick="alert('you clicked me')">Click me</button>`

But as your code grows in complexity, it'll hardly be one line long, so for readability sake, its advised to place your code inside the script tag:

```
<button onclick="firesOnClick()">Click me</button>
<script>
    var clicks = 0
    function firesOnClick() {
        clicks = clicks + 1
        alert('you clicked me ' + clicks + ' time(s)')
    }
</script>
```

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) has more information about it.