# Java Generic method : Sanitizing a list returned from database

Tags: java, list, security, arraylist

I was curious to know if we can have a common `generic` function to check for vulnerability for an `arraylist` that has returned `data` from `database`..Is there any java utility that we  can use or is it possible to create a single function that checks all type of `lists`. Currently i use a customized function for `List<String>`
but then i can have `List<Integer>, List<Object[]>, List<Object>`. Please advise what can i do better.
Below is my current function

```
public Boolean checkVulnerability(List<String> dataList)
{
   for(String data: dataList)
   {
     if(data!=null && !data.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") 
                && (data.contains("=") || data.contains("\\") ||
                        data.contains("<") || data.contains(">")))
        {
            //redirect to vulnerability page
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, only strings have the specific methods `trim()`, `contains(String)`, etc. It'd be better to have differently named methods for each kind of list

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you would sanitize List<Integer> or even List<Object>? I'm not aware of particular vulnerabilities on Integers.. However concerning Strings if you focus on XSS vulnerabilities you may want to use such a sanitizer, cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413297/how-to-sanitize-html-code-in-java-to-prevent-xss-attacks and similar. Other sanitizers will certainly vary strongly based on the very vulnerability you are trying to address. I'm not aware of something "universal" that would work for any string content (it would be too easy..).