# Error: FileNotFound thrown while trying to use antisamy-tinymce.xml OWASP

Tags: java, html, owasp, antisamy

I am working on a project that takes html from the user and persist to the DB. The current implementation is vulnerable to XSS attack.

In order to prevent this attack, I am trying to implement the OWASP Antisamy as seen [here](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project#tab=How_do_I_get_started_3F) but I am getting fileNotFoundError for the policy that I have downloaded and put in the resources directory of the project.

##### Code

```java
//sanitize welcomeMessage
try {
    Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(new File("antisamy-tinymce.xml"));
    AntiSamy as = new AntiSamy();
    CleanResults cr = as.scan(welcomeMessage, policy);
    preferences.setWelcomeMessage(cr.getCleanHTML());
} catch (PolicyException | ScanException e) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Invalid Welcome Message", e.getMessage()));
    return;
}
```

##### Project Structure

```
.
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── resources/
            ├── antisamy-tinymce.xml
```

Any pointer to what I might be doing wrongly?

I have tried using the absolute path of the antisamy-tinymce.xml file but it doesn't work when deployed to the application server.

Comment: I suggest you remove the 'esapi' tag here as this is not an ESAPI issue. You are using AntiSamy directly. I suggest you email one or both of the AntiSamy maintainers. You can find their email addresses on https://owasp.org/www-project-antisamy/ under "Leaders" listed on the right-hand side. Maybe add a tag for 'antisamy' in case anyone is watching for that. I don't really care to look into their code to see how it finds resources though, so ask them.

Comment: After several attempt at making this work, unfortunately it does not.

However, I found a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413297/how-to-sanitize-html-code-in-java-to-prevent-xss-attacks